# Pass variable globally on click event

Tags: jquery

I'm currently trying to make a header automatically responsive once the window width is bellow the navigation width like this

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    responsiveNav()
});

function responsiveNav() {

   var navWidth = $("#navigation").innerWidth();
   var windowWidth = $(window).width();

   if( windowWidth <= navWidth ) {
      // Make header responsive
   }

}
```

The thing is that the navigation width does not change on window resize. But it does change on some other events. How can I update the "navWidth" variable on certain click events and pass it globally so that I can use it within the responsiveNav function instead of always getting the navWidth on window resize?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the variable in a global scope and update it in other functions like

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    responsiveNav()
});

//declare the variable in a shared scope(like the global scope)
var navWidth;

function responsiveNav() {

    var windowWidth = $(window).width();

    if (windowWidth <= navWidth) {
        // Make header responsive
    }
}
//this could be an event handler or some other function
function someotherfunction() {
    navWidth = $("#navigation").innerWidth();
}
```